# How to group files by its extension using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to plot a pie chart which displays the size of a type of file.
I have a dataframe with many types of files: .jpg, .svg, .csv, etc. How can I group them by only using the extension (.csv, .jpg, etc) and NOT the whole name? Because when I plot the pie chart it displays many files with the same extension. And I only want to dipslay 1 extension.

THIS IS THE DATAFRAME

[image]

THIS IS MY CODE

```
#This is the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': ['filelist.xml', 'sheet002.htm', 'sheet005.htm', 'image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg',
   'kings.xls', 'Kings.png', 'Kings.xml', 'Riders.pdf', 'Royals.pdf', 'Royals.csv', 'Riders.xml'],
   'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *2 + ['2018-01-01 13:01:34'] *3 + ['2020-01-01 22:00:00'] *4 + ['2018-02-01 23:00:34']*3,
   'size':[8760] * 3 + [789] *4 + [863] *2 + [673] *3})

#here starts the analytics
df1=df.set_index('file_name')
df1.plot.pie(y='size', figsize=(7,7))
```

THIS IS THE PIE CHART

[image]

Comment: Do you want to plot the mean size or total size?

Comment: I want to plot the total size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': ['filelist.xml', 'sheet002.htm', 'sheet005.htm', 'image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg',
   'kings.xls', 'Kings.png', 'Kings.xml', 'Riders.pdf', 'Royals.pdf', 'Royals.csv', 'Riders.xml'],
   'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *2 + ['2018-01-01 13:01:34'] *3 + ['2020-01-01 22:00:00'] *4 + ['2018-02-01 23:00:34']*3,
   'size':[8760] * 3 + [789] *4 + [863] *2 + [673] *3})

#here starts the analytics
df['extension'] = df['file_name'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[1])
df.groupby('extension')['size'].sum().plot.pie(y='size', figsize=(7,7))
```

`x.rsplit('.', 1)` splits the text at last occurring `.` and `[1]` gives the second part which is the extension. Then it groups the dataframe using extension and plots the sum of sizes. Here's the output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: how does the ```r.split``` works? and why there is a ```[1]```?

Comment: `x.rsplit('.', 1)` splits the text at last occurring `.` and `[1]` gives the second part which is the extension.

Comment: everything works fine when I copy paste your code. But when I use my dataframe I get the following error: ```
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: I have a dataframe of 80039 rows x 6 columns

Comment: Is there any filename in your dataframe which doesn't have any extension? For this code this error can only come because of that.

Comment: Maybe. But I have noticed that there are files like this: .jpg and .JPG

Comment: These files should not be a problem. `df[df['file_name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.rsplit('.', 1))) < 2]` will tell you which rows are causing the problem. From that you can decide how to resolve it.

Comment: As I said earlier, `x.rsplit('.', 1)` splits the text at `.` but if there's no `.` in the text, this method will return a list with just 1 element. Checking if the length of return value is < 2 tells if there was a `.` in the text or not and if there wasn't, that means the text doesn't have a valid extension.